# PHP convert CSV to serialized array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, serialization

I have a CSV file with 2 columns, id and key. An extract is...

```
26,"test1
test2
test3
"
54,"test34
test52
test673
"
67,"test1
test2a
test333
"
```

I am trying to load this file into PHP and convert the second field (key) into a serialized array, I have this so far...

```
$filename = 'myfile.csv';

if (($h = fopen("{$filename}", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

      var_dump($data[1]);

    }

    fclose($h);

}
```

I am now trying to loop through the lines in $data[1] to convert them into an array, but when I do a var_dump the new lines seems to have disapeard. Am i approaching this the correct way?

Comment: whats this `a serialized array` an example of the that would be nice.  `Am i approaching this the correct way` - no as you need to store it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you meant by **a serialized array** here but I assume you want to make your `key` to be in a single line like below. **LET ME KNOW IF I AM WRONG**. So lets try like this way-

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'r');
$csvArray = array();
while ($row = fgetcsv($fp)) {
    $csvArray[$row[0]] = preg_replace("/[\r\n]/"," ",$row[1]);
}

fclose($fp);
print_r($csvArray);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
 [26] => test1 test2 test3 
 [54] => test34 test52 test673 
 [67] => test1 test2a test333 
)
```